# In Matthew 26:7 is the costly oil with which Jesus was anointed by the woman the oil prepared by Moses?

Tags: matthew, history, messiah

According to [Jewish tradition the oil Moses prepared in the wilderness](http://jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/1559-anointing) was supposed to reappear in the days of the messiah (which means "the one smeared with oil"):

> ...The oil of holy ointment prepared by Moses in the wilderness (Ex. xxx. 23 et seq.) had many miraculous qualities: it was never absorbed by the many spices mixed therewith; its twelve logs (1.68 gallons) were sufficient for the anointment of all the kings and high priests of Israelitish history, and will be in use in the Messianic time to come. During the reign of Josiah this oil was hidden away simultaneously with the holy ark, to reappear in the Messianic time (Hor. 11b et seq.; Sifra, Milluim, 1)...
>
> [Exo 30:22-38 KJV] 22 Moreover the LORD spake unto Moses, saying, 23 Take thou also unto thee principal spices, of pure myrrh five hundred [shekels], and of sweet cinnamon half so much, [even] two hundred and fifty [shekels], and of sweet calamus two hundred and fifty [shekels], 24 And of cassia five hundred [shekels], after the shekel of the sanctuary, and of oil olive an hin: 25 And thou shalt make it an oil of holy ointment, an ointment compound after the art of the apothecary: it shall be an holy anointing oil. 26 And thou shalt anoint the tabernacle of the congregation therewith, and the ark of the testimony, 27 And the table and all his vessels, and the candlestick and his vessels, and the altar of incense, 28 And the altar of burnt offering with all his vessels, and the laver and his foot. 29 And thou shalt sanctify them, that they may be most holy: whatsoever toucheth them shall be holy. 30 And thou shalt anoint Aaron and his sons, and consecrate them, that [they] may minister unto me in the priest's office. **31 And thou shalt speak unto the children of Israel, saying, This shall be an holy anointing oil unto me throughout your generations. 32 Upon man's flesh shall it not be poured, neither shall ye make [any other] like it, after the composition of it: it [is] holy, [and] it shall be holy unto you. 33 Whosoever compoundeth [any] like it, or whosoever putteth [any] of it upon a stranger, shall even be cut off from his people.** 34 And the LORD said unto Moses, Take unto thee sweet spices, stacte, and onycha, and galbanum; [these] sweet spices with pure frankincense: of each shall there be a like [weight]: 35 And thou shalt make it a perfume, a confection after the art of the apothecary, tempered together, pure [and] holy: 36 And thou shalt beat [some] of it very small, and put of it before the testimony in the tabernacle of the congregation, where I will meet with thee: it shall be unto you most holy. **37 And [as for] the perfume which thou shalt make, ye shall not make to yourselves according to the composition thereof: it shall be unto thee holy for the LORD. 38 Whosoever shall make like unto that, to smell thereto, shall even be cut off from his people.**

Although Jesus is called "the Christ" and "the Messiah" which both were terms identifying him as the son of David, heir to David's throne, he never seems to actually be anointed OR to become Israel's king, since the leadership (due to divine hardening) refused him!:

> [Jhn 19:15 KJV] 15 But they cried out, Away with [him], away with [him], crucify him. Pilate saith unto them, Shall I crucify your King? The chief priests answered, We have no king but Caesar.

But we do have this account suggesting that instead of being anointed by a prophet to become king he is anointed by a woman in preparation for his death:

> [Mat 26:6-13 KJV] 6 Now when Jesus was in Bethany, in the house of Simon the leper, 7 There came unto him a woman having an alabaster box of very precious ointment, and poured it on his head, as he sat [at meat]. 8 But when his disciples saw [it], they had indignation, saying, To what purpose [is] this waste? 9 For this ointment might have been sold for much, and given to the poor. 10 When Jesus understood [it], he said unto them, Why trouble ye the woman? for she hath wrought a good work upon me. 11 For ye have the poor always with you; but me ye have not always. 12 For in that she hath poured this ointment on my body, she did [it] for my burial. 13 Verily I say unto you, Wheresoever this gospel shall be preached in the whole world, [there] shall also this, that this woman hath done, be told for a memorial of her.

Is this story suggesting that the woman was anointing Christ with the fabled oil of Moses? Is this the missing anointing of the "Christ"? Was the woman a prophetess?

Alternatively, [was he being anointed as priest](http://jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/1559-anointing) (and would that still require her to be a prophetess)?:

> ...The rule is stated that every priest, whether the son of a high
> priest or not, had to be anointed. The son of a king was, however,
> exempt, except for special reasons, as in the case of Joash, because
> of Athaliah (II Kings, xi. 12); Solomon, because of Adonijah (I Kings,
> i. 39); and Jehu, because of Joram's claims (II Kings, ix. 1 et seq.);
> or of Jehoahaz, because Jehoiakim was two years his senior (II Kings,
> xxiii. 30). This rule was, however, modified, as indicated by the
> statement that David and Solomon were anointed from the horn (I Sam.
> xvi. 13; I Kings, i. 39) and Saul and Jehu from the cruse—pak (I Sam.
> x. 1; II Kings, ix. 3: the A. V. has "vial" and "box" in these
> respective passages). Another rule is mentioned, according to which
> the kings of the house of Israel were not anointed with the sacred oil
> at all. In their cases pure balsam was used instead; nor could the
> last reigning kings of Judah have been anointed with the sacred oil of
> consecration, since Josiah is said to have hidden it away (see Hor.
> 11b; Yer. Soṭah, viii. 22c; Yer. Hor. iii. 4c). Rabbinical tradition
> distinguishes also between the regular high priest and the priest
> anointed for the special purpose of leading in war—mashuaḥ milḥamah
> (Soṭah, viii. 1; Yoma, 72b, 73a). According to tradition (see
> Josippon, xx.; Chronicle of Jerahmeel, xci. 3; compare I Macc. iii.
> 55), Judas Maccabeus was anointed as priest for the war before he
> proclaimed the words prescribed in Deut. xx. 1-9.  Anointing stands
> for greatness (Sifre, Num. 117; Yer. Bik. ii. 64d): consequently,
> "Touch not mine anointed" signifies "my great ones." All the vessels
> of the tabernacle, also, were consecrated with the sacred oil for all
> time to come (Num. R. xii.).

Comment: No. The anointing of a king or priest or prophet (on one hand), and the anointing (or embalming) of the dead, are two different things. Christ explicitly links it with the latter (John 12:7). See also John 19:39.

Comment: It is starting to look like Jesus never was the Christ!

Comment: @Lucian While linked to his death it was not an embalming since he hadn't finished his falafal yet.

Comment: It was a sign or symbol of His soon-to-follow death-and-embalming.

Comment: Do we know from history of any such "allow us to show you the door" ceremonies?!

Comment: (I don't want to sound like De Niro, but was your last comment addressed at me ? If so, what did it mean ?)

Comment: @Lucian Yes, to you (doing my best Devito). I mean, was it common to start celebrating so soon (before they are dead)?

Comment: Celebrating what ?

Comment: The "soon-to-be death and embalming". Did Jews preemptively perform rituals for the dead?

Comment: I said it was a sign or symbol of that which was soon to come. See Acts 21:11, for instance.

Comment: A prophetic symbol?

Comment: I found this relevant page, apparently from the Orthodox tradition:  

https://www.theperfumechronicles.com/chronicles/nard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The oil used on Jesus was:

> Mark 14:3
>   a woman came with an alabaster jar of perfumed oil, **genuine nard**, very expensive.. .

The oil of the Mosaic law was:

> Exodus 30:22-25 NWT
>   Jehovah continued to speak to Moses: 23 “Next, take the choicest perfumes: 500 units of solidified myrrh, and half that amount, 250 units, of sweet cinnamon, 250 units of sweet calamus, 24 and 500 units of cassia, measured by the standard shekel of the holy place, along with a hin of olive oil. 25 Then make out of it a holy anointing oil; it should be skillfully blended together. It is to be a holy anointing oil.

Notice no "nard".

So the answer to your question is no.

Comment: Actually, there seem to be several different anointings. One is at table 2 days before Passover, another 6 days before Passover and the other is at the tomb after Jesus was raised.